# Better color depth using Terminal Services from a high res client

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, colors, color-depth

I've got myself a new screen running a resolution of 2560 x 1440.

When I start a Remote Desktop Connection I set the Display configuration to "Full screen" and the Color depth to 24 bit.

But once the connection is established I'm downgraded to 256 colors on my client connection.

I think it has something to do with the rather high resolution on my screen. If I change the resolution on the Remote Desktop Connection to something else than "Full screen" I do get better Color Depth.

Is there some way I can achieve better color depth and still keep my client connection displaying full screen.

I often work "inside" a RDC all day, so it would be nice have a better experience.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The colour depth may be limited by Group Policy.  There are some potentially useful details in the MSKB article [HOW TO: Connect to Terminal Services with Color Resolution That Is Greater Than 256 in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278502).

Comment: Thank you for the link. But I don't think that's it as I have no problem doing 24-bit if I lower the resolution (anything that's not full screen)